# Python Requests Log In

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to build a log in code using python requests for this form *(see html code below)*

**My goal:**

I just want to log in to this website using python requests. I already have coded the python script but when I run it, nothing is happening. I'm wondering what am I missing.

I have tried to follow the tutorials i found in google but none of them works.

**here's my Python code:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36'
}

login_data = {
    "username": "myusername",
    "password": "mysupersecurepassword",
    "tradingpin": "123456"
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    url = "https://my.website.com/"
    r = s.get(url, headers=headers)
    print(r.text)

    # Make a post request to website
    r = s.post(url, data=login_data, headers=headers)
```

**HTML FORM**

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <input id="hdnToken" name="token" type="hidden" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="u-value" class="ph-tooltip-T form-control" value="">
  <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" class="ph-tooltip-T form-control" value="">
  <i onclick="togglePwVisibility()" id="eye" class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open form-control-feedback"></i>
  <a href="https://login.website.com/" style="color: darkslategray;font-size: 11px;" class="btn-link">Forgot your password?</a>
  <h5>Advanced Option:</h5>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkTrading" name="isTPinAutoFill" onclick="toggleTradingPIN()"> Auto-fill Trading PIN </label>
  <i>Save and pre-fill your Trading PIN during trading transactions.</i>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="password" id="txtTradingPin" name="tradingPIN" class="ph-tooltip-T form-control" placeholder="Trading PIN" maxlength="4" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" value="">
  <button type="submit" id="loginButton" style="background-color: #333333;width: 25%;color: ghostwhite" class="ph-button1 btn btn-default">LOGIN</button>
</form>
```

**Issues**

1. Input or Forms don't have the name attribute.
2. The python code that i have written doesn't do anything? Its as if nothing happened. I checked the `print(r.text)` and it returned the hml code for the log in page. So i think the POST request was not executed.

Comment: Exactly what are you expecting the code to do? You have put the line `print(r.text)` in the code. Is it not printing the expected value?

Comment: just log in to this website.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion but I have updated my question to show my goal.

Comment: Well, i don't see how you are getting the information that it has not been logged in. It might have rather actually logged in. Have you checked with `print(r.text)` after the post request to see whether it has already logged in or not?

Comment: yeah i did, I have checked it and it shows the html codes for the log in page. its as if the post request are not executed.

Comment: In your html form file, there is no 'name' attribute to either username or password. Can you try replacing `<input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="u-value" class="ph-tooltip-T form-control" value="">` with `<input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="u-value" class="ph-tooltip-T form-control" value="" name="username">` and `<input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" class="ph-tooltip-T form-control" value="">` with `<input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" class="ph-tooltip-T form-control" value="" name="password">`?

Comment: The thing is, I cannot do that. This is because I don't own the website. it's a public website and the way the forms are built are just like that.

Comment: I don't think input values of a form can be sumbitted to the server without name attributes. Perhaps some javascript code is being used in the background to assign names to those values. Is the html form code the entire code that exists in the html page? Or does more code exist in the page?

Comment: It seems you're trying to log into some type of financial services application. You should know that these types of services generally employ extreme security measures to prevent this sort of automated processing, which in the past has largely been executed by malicious actors using stolen account credentials. Your best bet would be to use a browser emulation suite (like Selenium or Puppeteer) to most accurately emulate an end-user's browser, but even then it's not a sure-fire thing that their security measures wouldn't pick up on this.

Comment: "*I checked the print(r.text) and it returned the hml code for the log in page.*" Can you elaborate on what you *expected* from this call? `r`, at the time of invocation of `print(r.text)`, corresponds to the GET you've called on the login URL. How is it that you'd expect anything else other than the login page's HTML to be present there?

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to what the accepted answer would have you believe, the algorithm isn't that complex. It appears on the surface as Base64, but it's been double-encoded (not clear exactly *why* this is, however).

The generation algorithm in pseudocode would be:

```
Token = base64_encode(base64_encode(username) + ":" + base64_encode(password))
```

All you need to do is send the form data along (with `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header) in a POST to properly emulate what your browser is doing on your behalf.

It's still not clear if there are any security mechanisms in place on the target site that would prevent the success of this sort of automated consumption of the site.

Comment: since this is a base64, is it still possible to decode the 'token' using the tools online?

Comment: "*... is it.... possible to decode the 'token' using the tools online?*" Sure is - that's exactly how I figured the algorithm out.

Comment: I tried but it didn't return my correct log in credentials. anyway, got my way in the site. about the site, its a trading platform and i'm just trying to scrape the live stock prices.

Comment: "*I tried but it didn't return my correct log in credentials*" What did it return? Using `example_user` and `example_pass`, and following this algorithm, the Token generated is `WlhoaGJYQnNaVjkxYzJWeTpaWGhoYlhCc1pWOXdZWE56`. When decoded, the string evaluates to `ZXhhbXBsZV91c2Vy:ZXhhbXBsZV9wYXNz`. When each component separated by the colon `:` character is decoded again, I'm left with `example_user:example_pass`. Can you elaborate on what it *did* return for you?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can login with this site, because `login` request requires body like this:

```
token=Basic+ZFhObGNtNWhiV1U9Ok1USXpORFUy&isTPinAutoFill=on&tradingPIN=1234
```

And this is what I've inputed

```
username='username'
password='123456'
pin='1234'
```

If you don't know the algorithm that encode the `username & password`, then no way to login.

[image]

Comment: Hi Lucas, i already figured it out before you answered it. I upvoted your answer because we have the same method on figuring this out. the thing is, the "Token" is all you need to log in. This website (im not sure if its the correct term) encrypts your username and password then issues you a "unique" token. That token will be sent to the server instead of the conventional username and password.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing r.text before posting any data to the website. Try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36'
}

login_data = {
    "username": "myusername",
    "password": "mysupersecurepassword",
    "tradingpin": "123456"
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    url = "https://my.website.com/"
    # r = s.get(url, headers=headers) THIS DOES NOTHING
    # print(r.text)

    # Make a post request to website
    r = s.post(url, data=login_data, headers=headers)
    print(r.content)
    # with soup:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    print(soup)
```

You should be able to find your username and password in the html. If so it means that you have successfully logged in!

Answer (score -1):

This website is kind of special in some way. Sorry, newbie and this is the first time I encountered this kind of log in process.

The thing is, the "Token" is all you need to log in. This website (im not sure if its the correct term) encrypts your username and password then issues you a "unique" token. That token will be sent to the server instead of the conventional username and password.

So to address my log in issue, all i need to do is to just change the `login_data` to this:

```
login_data = {
    'token': 'Basic easkdhkajjkadjknaskjdhajks'
}
```

where `easkdhkajjkadjknaskjdhajks` is the unique token issued to every user.

Comment: It's pretty misleading to call this "encryption", when in reality it's only "encoding"; the two are absolutely not the same. Additionally, the "Token" is not "issued" by any authority, it's calculated on the client based on a predictable algorithm.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the info. as i have mentioned, im a newbie so everything is new to me. Thanks for correcting.